# How to convert COleVariant to CString c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have this in my MFC:

```
CByteArray data;  data.SetSize(9);
data[0]='*';
data[1]=xG;
data[2]=',';
data[3]=yG;
data[4]=',';
data[5]=xL;
data[6]=',';
data[7]=yL;
data[8]='#';

if(m_comm.get_PortOpen()){ //mscomm serial
    UpdateData(TRUE);
    m_comm.put_Output(COleVariant(data));

    m_StrKirim=COleVariant(data);

    UpdateData(FALSE);
}
```

The result `m_StrKirim` was like Chinese character idk.

The objective is I want to make data (array) to one string and copy it to `CString` variable and display it to `m_StrKirim` (Edit Control)

I tried tutorials with keyword `COleVariant` to `CString`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no obvious reason why this would not work, OleVariant has the plumbing to turn a CByteArray into a COM-compatible SAFEARRAY and that should keep MSComm happy.  It is not a string and you definitely don't want to do anything with a CString.  If you see "Chinese", the typical outcome of interpreting binary data as a Unicode string, then consider that it is a problem with the code that receives this data or whatever tool you use to look at the output.  Removing the dependency on MSComm would be wise btw, it is long past its expiration date.

Answer (score 2):

Although `CString` has a constructor that takes a `VARIANT` as input, converting a byte array to a `CString` via OLE doesn't make much sense.

Your byte array represents an ASCII string, so you need to tell `CString` to treat the byte array as a `char` string.  `CString` has a constructor that accepts a `char*` and length as input, and will convert the `char` data to `CString`'s native character type as needed.

Try this:

```
m_StrKirim = CString(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.GetData()), data.GetSize());
```

Comment: Note, that the [CString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt) conversion c'tors can be disabled by setting the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor symbol. It's probably also advisable to call [data.GetSize()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cobarray-class#getsize) instead of using a magic value. The cast should also specify `char const*` as its destination type.

Comment: @IInspectable good point about `GetSize`. The `const` cast is not necessary, though. `data` is not `const`, and a `char *` variable can be passed to a `char const *` parameter.